# SettingwithCopy when creating new column and when dropping NaN rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, chained-assignment

I've been searching around reading the pandas docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) and trying different lines of code from questions posted around [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835483/confusion-re-pandas-copy-of-slice-of-dataframe-warning) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340246/copy-warning-in-pandas-series) and I can't seem to get away from the setting with copy warning. I'd prefer to learn to code it the "right" way as opposed to just [ignoring the warnings.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

The following lines of code are inside a for loop and I don't want to generate this warning a lot of times because it could slow things down.

I'm trying to make a new column with name: 'E'+vs where vs is a string in a list in the for loop

But for each one of them, I still get the following warning, even with the last 3 lines:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Here are the troublesome lines I've tried so far:

```
#based on research, the first two seem to be the "wrong" way

df_out['E'+vs] = df_out[kvs].rolling(v).mean().copy()
df_out['E'+vs] = df_out[kvs].rolling(v).mean()

df_out.loc[:,'E'+vs] = df_out[kvs].rolling(v).mean().copy()
df_out.loc[:,'E'+vs] = df_out[kvs].rolling(v).mean()
df_out.loc[:,'E'+vs] = df_out.loc[:,kvs].rolling(v).mean()
```

The other one that gives a SettingWithCopyWarning is this:

```
df_out.dropna(inplace=True,axis=0)
```

This one also gave a warning (but I figured this one would)

```
df_out = df_out.dropna(inplace=True,axis=0)
```

How do I do both of these operations correctly?

EDIT: Here is the code that produced the original df_out

```
df_out= pd.concat([vol.Date[1:-1], ret.Return_Time[:-2], vol.Freq_Time[:-2],
               vol.Freq_Time[:-1].shift(-1), vol.Freq_Time[:].shift(-2)],
               axis=1).dropna().set_index('Date')
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a confusing topic.  It's not the code you've posted that is the problem.  It's the code you haven't posted.  It's the code that generated the `df_out`

Consider this example and note the last line that generates the warning.

```
df_other = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1], B=[2]))
df_out = df_other[:]

df_out['E'] = 5
```

> ```
> //anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
> ```

Now we'll try an equivalent thing that won't produce the warning

```
df_other = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1], B=[2]))
df_out = df_other.loc[:]

df_out['E'] = 5
```

Then

```
print `df_out`

   A  B  E
0  1  2  5
```

---

It boils down to pandas deciding to attach an `is_copy` attribute to a dataframe when it's constructed  based on lots of criteria.

Notice the

```
df_other[:].is_copy

<weakref at 0x103323458; to 'DataFrame' at 0x116a684e0>
```

When

```
df_other.loc[:].is_copy
```

Returns `None`

---

So what types of construction trigger the copy?  I still don't know everything, and not even the things I know all make sense to me.

Like why does this not trigger it?

```
df_other[['A', 'B', 'E']].is_copy
```

Comment: Interesting answer. Definitely not clear cut as to what pandas is really doing. My use case is as follows.

 I have an original df that gets passed into a function containing those two operations. So say, the initial len(df_out) = 1000. After the operations len(df_out) =998. Then I do other stuff. But the next time I iterate, I still want len(df_out) =1000, i.e the original dataframe. So to solve this, before going into the function i did df_out  = df[:] to make a copy of the original dataframe. That I now pass into the function. All works right but this stupid warning is annoying.

Comment: I checked id(df) does not equal id(df_out). Kind of annoying that the value is passed by reference gets changed. So iteration 1, the len goes from 1000 to 998 because of the dropped rows, then iteration 2 the len starts from 998 to 996 and so forth, which is wrong as it should start from 1000 again.

Comment: Still havent figured it out. I'll sleep on it.

Comment: it was as simple as doing df.copy() 
....facepalm lol

Answer (score 2):

First off, I am not sure this is either efficient or the best approach. However, I had the same issue when I was adding a new column to the exist dataframe and I decided to use reset_index method.

Here I first drop Nan rows from EMPLOYEES column and assign this manipulated data frame to new data frame df1 then I add COMPANY_SIZE column to the df1 as follows:

```
df1 = all_merged_years.dropna(subset=['EMPLOYEES']).reset_index()

column = df1['EMPLOYEES']

Size =[]

df1['COMPANY_SIZE'] = ' '

for number in column:
    if number <=999:
        Size.append('Small')
    elif 999<number<=9999:
        Size.append('Medium')
    elif 9999<number:
        Size.append('Large')
    else:
        Size.append('UNKNOWN')

df1['COMPANY_SIZE'] = Size
```

This way I did NOT get a warning as such. Hope that helps.